# Relationship between vertex cut and edge cut

Tags: graph, graph-theory

In general is there any relationship between the minimum vertex cut and the minimum edge cut of a graph?

I'm in a situation where I have computed the minimum edge cut of a graph.  Now I want to find the minimum vertex cut of the same graph, and I was wondering if I could obtain a good estimate by simply computing a vertex cut from the minimum edge cut.  That is, I would simply find a subset of vertices such that they cover all the edges in the edge cut.

However, I'm not sure if this approach would actually yield a good estimate of the minimum vertex cut, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

yes. cardinality of vertex cut is K(G) is less or equal to the cardinality of edge cut.